# Why does pp-macroexpand return nonsense for cl-loop?

Tags: cl-lib, macroexpansion

Consider the following `cl-loop`:

```lisp
(cl-loop for x across "abc"
         for y across "123"
         concat (string x y))
```

This evaluates to `"a1b2c3"`, i.e. it zips both strings together. However, if I look at the expansion of `cl-loop` it seems like that should not be possible, as

```lisp
(pp-macroexpand-expression
 '(cl-loop for x across "abc"
           for y across "123"
           concat (string x y)))
```

expands to (comments by me)

```lisp
(cl-block nil
  (let*
      ((--cl-vec-- "abc")      ; --cl-vec-- set to "abc"
       (--cl-idx-- -1)
       (x nil)
       (--cl-vec-- "123")      ; --cl-vec-- set again, this time to "123"
       (--cl-idx-- -1)
       (y nil)
       (--cl-var-- ""))
    (while
        (and
         (setq --cl-idx--
               (1+ --cl-idx--))
         (< --cl-idx--
            (length --cl-vec--))
         (progn
           (setq x
                 (aref --cl-vec-- --cl-idx--))  ; A
           (setq --cl-idx--
                 (1+ --cl-idx--)))
         (< --cl-idx--                          ; C
            (length --cl-vec--)))              
      (setq y
            (aref --cl-vec-- --cl-idx--))       ; B
      (cl-callf concat --cl-var--
        (string x y)))
    --cl-var--))
```

However, when I try to evaluate *that* it only returns `"12"`, which is expected, since `x` will refer to `"1"` at `A` and `y` will refer to `B`at `A`, and then `--cl-idx--` will be `4` in the next iteration `C` and thus end the loop.

That's not how the original code can work, so `cl-loop` cannot expand into that form. How can I get the *actual* macro expansion with proper identifiers?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [phils](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/454/phils) pointed out, the reason is that those symbols are uninterned.  You can set `print-gensym` and `print-circle` to `t` to get uninterned symbols to print correctly.  Once that is done, the expansion becomes

```lisp
(cl-block nil
  (let*
      ((#2=#:--cl-vec-- "abc")
       (#1=#:--cl-idx-- -1)
       (x nil)
       (#4=#:--cl-vec-- "123")
       (#3=#:--cl-idx-- -1)
       (y nil)
       (#5=#:--cl-var-- ""))
    (while
    (and
     (setq #1#
           (1+ #1#))
     (< #1#
        (length #2#))
     (progn
       (setq x
         (aref #2# #1#))
       (setq #3#
         (1+ #3#)))
     (< #3#
        (length #4#)))
      (setq y
        (aref #4# #3#))
      (cl-callf concat #5#
    (string x y)))
    #5#))
```

which correctly evaluates to `"a1b2c3"`.

Comment: Ah, so my call above should be wrapped around with `(let ((print-gensym t) (print-circle t)) (pp-macroexpand-expression ...))`. That's good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `--cl-vec--` and `--cl-idx--` symbols (and other similarly-named symbols, should you see any) are uninterned, and there may be more than one of each.

You're only seeing the printed representation of those symbols, and consequently `read`ing that code does not produce something equivalent to the original code, as the symbols being read that way will get interned and clash in a way that did not originally happen.

<del>I think to get `read`able code, you would need to replace all `make-symbol` instances with `gensym` or `cl-gensym` in the relevant macro and function definitions.</del>  (Edit: @d125q has shown how to achieve this without modifying anything in cl-lib.)